# How to verify whether a div tag is present or not using Selenium WebDriver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

How to verify whether a div tag is present or not using Selenium WebDriver in C#?

On my web page, I would like to verify whether for the below div tag, to ensure that the data is displayed. What is the right way of doing this?

```
div data-bind="visible: displayFeatureExposures" style=""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((By.XPath("//div[contains(@data-bind, 'displayFeatureExposures')]"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want to rely on exception to determine whether the element exists or not, you can use `FindElements()` and check for the number of elements returned :

```
string query = "//div[@data-bind='visible: displayFeatureExposures']";
bool isExists = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(query)).Count > 0;
```